# Passportjs req.logout() not working after moving to separate file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using NodeJS with Express as the backend for a dashboard web app. I have started splitting the backend server code into smaller files (each route is in it's own file). I split the login function successfully, however when I split the logout function not only does this break the logout function, but it also breaks the login function.

login.js

```
module.exports = function (passport) {
  const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

  //Login
  router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).send([user, 'Cannot log in', info]);
      }

      req.login(user, err => {
        res.send('Logged in');
        console.log('User logged in');
      });
    })(req, res, next);
  });

  return router;
};
```

logout.js

```
module.exports = function () {
  const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

  //Logout
  router.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.logout();

    console.log('Logged out');

    return res.send();
  });

  return router;
};
```

require/use in index.js

```
const loginRoute = require('./routes/login.js')(passport);
exprApp.use('/api', loginRoute);
const logoutRoute = require('./routes/logout.js');
exprApp.use('/api', logoutRoute);
```

login.js works the same as before when logout.js is not split off so I don't think the issue lies there. Maybe it's because the res.send is never actually sent to the frontend somehow, so it never reaches the .then? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit: I am using Vue in the frontend. Here is the code for handling the response. It never seems to reach the callback, and therefore router.push, etc. are not executed it just hangs.

```
logOut: ({commit}) => {
    axios.get("/api/logout")
        .then(() => {
        router.push("/");
        commit('RESET_USER');
        commit('RESET_DEALERSHIPS');
        commit('RESET_LEADS');
    })
        .catch((errors) => {    
        console.log(errors);
    });
}
```

The 'Logged out' text from logout.js is logged to the browser's console, so the endpoint must exist and be reachable by the frontend (and no errors are logged).

Comment: What do you mean by "break the logout function"? Any error that occurs?

Comment: From a quick test, you can't re-use routes with the same path. Defining `/api` more than once will only ever use the first one.

Comment: I've added some extra detail to the original question. Defining different paths has solved the login issue, but logout still doesn't work correctly (router.push is never called).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by simply changing the line

```
exprApp.use('/api/logout', logoutRoute);
```

To

```
exprApp.use('/api/logout', logoutRoute());
```

I don't know why this works but it solves the issue. As a side note, if I change loginRoute to also use the brackets I get an error from Node.